# Separate cell value and take part of it

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a solution for my problem. I have a table, and there is column, which contains words separate with dots. I want to take only one part of that word. I know about `Substring_Index` but my problem is, that word i want to take is on random position. e.g
Project1.Test1
Project1.Subproject1.Test2
Test21.Project4
I want to take only part with Test word and number. How can i take it from whole cell value

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a table Projects with column Project:

```
WITH Projects AS (
    SELECT CONCAT( Project , '.' ) AS project, LOCATE('Test', Project) AS Position
    FROM Projects)
SELECT Project, substring(Project,Position,LOCATE('.',Project,Position)- Position) 
from Projects;
```

Here's the same query without the CTE:

```
SELECT Project, substring(Project,Position,LOCATE('.',Project,Position)- 
   Position) 
FROM (SELECT CONCAT(Project,'.') AS Project, LOCATE('Test',Project) AS 
  Position
FROM Projects) AS Projects;
```

In the CTE, add a dot and find the position of the word Test. In the outer query return the string starting at the Position and find the dot after that position. Subtract the two positions.

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL dont have WITH function. I do it in this way:

`Select Substring( q.name, Locate('Test', q.name),  Locate('.', Substring( q.name, Locate('Test', q.name)))-1);`

Comment: MySQL does have a  Common Table expression. I just used it to simplify the query. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql_with.htm

Comment: I try to use it in MySQL workbench and get error `unexpected WITH`

Comment: Looks like WITH needs at least version 8.0. You can easily change what I did to a subquery.